# Get the output of pyinstaller from console

Tags: python, file, user-interface, exe, pyinstaller

I have a python script which I convert to the .EXE file using the pyinstaller. In my script I create a GUI where user can type numbers or text in the box and they are shown on the screen. However assume after displaying the data on the screen you will save them in a .CSV file (By modifying the script to save the data to the file).  I would like to know is there anyway to do the same thing with the .EXE file and save the output to a separate file.

UPDATE: The reason why this is strange is  because you are saving the file in your directory which does not exist on the destination laptop and there is no way to interact with the EXE file.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have the script that reads the input and save it to a file. However this saves the file in my directory and I do not know what happens when this file is sent to somebody else because that directory does not exist on the his/her laptop. There is no way to interact with the EXE file. This is where I am stuck as how to save the data from EXE file to the file.

Comment: You may, for example, set path for the file like `os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "myfile.txt")` and it will be located next to your executable.

Comment: The most robust solution would be to prompt the user for an output file path in the GUI.